# Elgato Game Capture. CPU or GPU for encode/decode?

Tags: cpu, gpu, encoding, video-capture, decoding

On my old PC that I use for my Elgato, I am unsure wether I need to use my CPU or GPU for Encoding and Decoding.

The CPU is a Core2 Duo E6550 @2.33GHz. The GPU is a GT 730.

Ya, it's pretty bad. My new PC is muchmuchmuch better but that is my gaming one, not the recording one.

My guess is that I need to use my CPU because the clock speed is better (the GPU is ~900MHz).

**What should I use for Encode/Decode? CPU or GPU?**

Thanks!

P.S. I wasn't sure if this is the right Stack Exchange.

Comment: How and what choices are offered?

Comment: @sawdust Encode in program settings (not Elgato device settings) gives "Built-In (Software)" and "NVIDIA (Hardware)". Decode shows the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with GPU for recording as it will always allow more headroom for what you are trying to accomplish.

The video card was invented with the premise of allowing separate hardware to process video. The CPU was made just to process everything else.

GPU regardless of how slow is still a number one go to for anything video related.

Comment: Thanks, after testing a GPU recording (I used CPU before this), it works much better :)